# SQL Server SELECT statement - how to get the info needed

Tags: sql-server, database, select, server

Calculate monthly number of orders based on order date for each customer separately

1. custID, Order date, Number of orders
2. custID, Name, Order date, Number of orders

So, I do know how it works counting it monthly, but I don't know how to obtain it monthly for each customer. Any ideas?

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) AS "number of orders"
FROM   
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY 
    Month(OrderDate)
```

It's using the `AdventureWorks` database in the table `Sales.SalesOrderHeader` and there is enough information to count it, but I cannot think of a statement.

Comment: If you can get a monthly total already (presumably overall), then all you need to do is add the `Customer` field to your `SELECT` list _and_ to your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Show us what you already have.

Comment: I got: 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "number of orders" FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader GROUP BY month(OrderDate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `custID` and `Year(OrderDate)` in `Groupby` to get the count of orders placed by each customer per month and without `year` in group by you may get wrong count.

```
SELECT custid,
       Month(OrderDate),
       Year(OrderDate),
       Count(*) [AS number of orders]
FROM   Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP  BY custid,
          Month(OrderDate),
          Year(OrderDate)
```